# How to compile OpenCV for iOS7 (arm64)

Tags: python, ios, opencv, ios7

Compiling Xcode Project fails with following errors:
['missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/***/Git/ocr/opencv2.framework/opencv2'](http://pastebin.com/WC9Tbe8L)

It works well, if i change Architectures(under Build Settings) to (armv7, armv7s) instead of (armv7, armv7s).

How to change the opencv python build script, to add arm64 support to opencv2.framework?

Comment: You might be better asking this on OpenCV's [StackOverflow clone](http://answers.opencv.org/questions/).  As is usually the case documentation is very thin on the ground with OpenCV.

Comment: I was just now able to build tagged version 2.4.8, which is from Dec 27 2013, without any trouble. (Master failed, though.) Xcode 5.0.2 and OS X 10.9.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The latest OpenCV iOS framework supports 64 bit by default

It can be downloaded at: [OpenCV download page](http://opencv.org/downloads.html)

Answer (score 5):

I modified the following to make it build, though I haven't got an arm64 iOS device to test at the moment.

**Edit**: I also had to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/17025423/1094400

Assuming "opencv" is the folder containing the opencv source from Github:

in each of `gzlib.c, gzread.c, gzwrite.c` located in `opencv/3rdparty/zlib/` add:

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

at the top after the existing include.

In addition open `opencv/platforms/ios/cmake/Modules/Platform/iOS.cmake` and change line 88 from:

```
set (CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)" CACHE string  "Build architecture for iOS")
```

to:

```
set (CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT)" CACHE string  "Build architecture for iOS")
```

Furthermore change the buildscript at `opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py` in lines 99 and 100 from:

```
targets = ["iPhoneOS", "iPhoneOS", "iPhoneSimulator"]
archs = ["armv7", "armv7s", "i386"]
```

to:

```
targets = ["iPhoneOS", "iPhoneOS", "iPhoneOS", "iPhoneSimulator", "iPhoneSimulator"]
archs = ["armv7", "armv7s", "arm64", "i386", "x86_64"]
```

The resulting library will include the following:

```
$ xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info opencv2
    Architectures in the fat file: opencv2 are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64
```

Although I have a remaining concern regarding `opencv/platforms/ios/cmake/Toolchain-iPhoneOS_Xcode.cmake` which defines the size of a data pointer to be 4 in lines 14 and 17.
It should be 8 for 64bit I guess, so as I haven't tested if the compiled library is working for arm64 I would suggest further investigations at this point if it does not run properly.

Comment: Just a quick note to all who end up here: OpenCV now supports arm64 by default, so just go download the latest OpenCV iOS framework.

Answer (score 2):

micahp's answer was almost perfect, but missed the simulator version. So modify platforms/ios/build_framework.py to:

```
targets = ["iPhoneOS", "iPhoneOS", "iPhoneOS", "iPhoneSimulator", "iPhoneSimulator"]
archs = ["armv7", "armv7s", "arm64", "i386", "x86_64"]
```

You'll need to download the command line tools for Xcode 5.0.1 and then run

```
python opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py ios
```

Comment: Can you upload the compiled framework and provide a link. I am still getting errors

Comment: This still fails to build. It appears zlib fails to build for 64-bit targets. iOS provides zlib, so I don't know if it would be possible for OpenCV to use that. I spent far too much time trying to modify the build to get it to work, but I failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait a next month. Will release a new XCode with more powerful supporting of 32/64 bit.

https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=9162013a

Answer (score 0):

Modify "build_frameworks.py" to:

```
def build_framework(srcroot, dstroot):
    "main function to do all the work"

    targets = ["iPhoneOS", "iPhoneOS", "iPhoneOS", "iPhoneSimulator"]
    archs = ["armv7", "armv7s", "arm64", "i386"]
    for i in range(len(targets)):
        build_opencv(srcroot, os.path.join(dstroot, "build"), targets[i], archs[i])

    put_framework_together(srcroot, dstroot)
```

Comment: Tried changing the script as you suggested but wasn't able to buid

Answer (score 0):

@Jan, I followed your instructions, but OpenCV still doesn't run on arm64. You made such a detailed and wonderful answer - why not check it out on a simulator and see if you can make it run? :-)

FWIW, I think it might be harder than it seems. On the openCV stackoverflow clone, there's an indication that this problem might be [non-trivial](http://answers.opencv.org/question/21260/how-to-compile-opencv-for-ios7-arm64/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using terminal commands given in the opencv installation guide in official website, use the following commands. Worked for me.

cd OpenCV-2.3.1

mkdir build

cd build

cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..

make

sudo make install

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar error, but the issue wasn't related with the arm64 coompilation.fixed adding the framework libc++.dylib