# How to compile openCV for iphone5s ios 64bit

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, build, arm64

cloned openCV and [modified the build script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976893/how-to-compile-opencv-for-ios7-arm64) to include 64bit arm according to suggested answer

But getting many errors and it is not building.

Any work around for this?

I can post the log if needed.

Comment: Latest version of OpenCV framework, supports arm64 architecture.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976893/how-to-compile-opencv-for-ios7-arm64?lq=1

Comment: You can supply an answer! Will select it :) thanks