# How to build OpenCV 2.4.8 for iOS7?

Tags: opencv, ios7, build, arm64

I try to get my EyeTracking system running again. I know there are already some questions covering the same issue ([How to compile OpenCV for iOS7 (arm64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976893/how-to-compile-opencv-for-ios7-arm64)), but nothing of that worked for me. The latest release on github has already all the arm64 architecture add ons build in. So I dont have to change the python build_framwork.py. But following the build instructions for the framework on OpenCV documentation (http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html#ios-installation) brings up the following error in terminal:

```
sh: cmake: command not found
User defaults from command line:
    IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks = 8

Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = armv7
    IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 6.0
    SDKROOT = iphoneos7.0

xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/julesair/Open_CV/ios/build/iPhoneOS-armv7 does not contain an Xcode project.

Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = armv7
    IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 6.0
    SDKROOT = iphoneos7.0

xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/julesair/Open_CV/ios/build/iPhoneOS-armv7 does not contain an Xcode project.

    sh: cmake: command not found
    User defaults from command line:
        IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks = 8

    Build settings from command line:
        ARCHS = armv7s
        IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 6.0
        SDKROOT = iphoneos7.0

    xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/julesair/Open_CV/ios/build/iPhoneOS-armv7s does not contain an Xcode project.

    Build settings from command line:
        ARCHS = armv7s
        IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 6.0
        SDKROOT = iphoneos7.0

    xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/julesair/Open_CV/ios/build/iPhoneOS-armv7s does not contain an Xcode project.

    sh: cmake: command not found
    User defaults from command line:
        IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks = 8

    Build settings from command line:
        ARCHS = arm64
        IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 6.0
        SDKROOT = iphoneos7.0

    xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/julesair/Open_CV/ios/build/iPhoneOS-arm64 does not contain an Xcode project.

    Build settings from command line:
        ARCHS = arm64
        IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 6.0
        SDKROOT = iphoneos7.0

    xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/julesair/Open_CV/ios/build/iPhoneOS-arm64 does not contain an Xcode project.

    sh: cmake: command not found
    User defaults from command line:
        IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks = 8

    Build settings from command line:
        ARCHS = i386
        IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 6.0
        SDKROOT = iphonesimulator7.0

    xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/julesair/Open_CV/ios/build/iPhoneSimulator-i386 does not contain an Xcode project.

    Build settings from command line:
        ARCHS = i386
        IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 6.0
        SDKROOT = iphonesimulator7.0

    xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/julesair/Open_CV/ios/build/iPhoneSimulator-i386 does not contain an Xcode project.

    sh: cmake: command not found
    User defaults from command line:
        IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks = 8

    Build settings from command line:
        ARCHS = x86_64
        IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 6.0
        SDKROOT = iphonesimulator7.0

    xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/julesair/Open_CV/ios/build/iPhoneSimulator-x86_64 does not contain an Xcode project.

    Build settings from command line:
        ARCHS = x86_64
        IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 6.0
        SDKROOT = iphonesimulator7.0

    xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/julesair/Open_CV/ios/build/iPhoneSimulator-x86_64 does not contain an Xcode project.

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 112, in <module>
        build_framework(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), "../..")), os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1]))
      File "opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 104, in build_framework
        put_framework_together(srcroot, dstroot)
      File "opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 80, in put_framework_together
        shutil.copytree(tdir0 + "/install/include/opencv2", dstdir + "/Headers")
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 171, in copytree
        names = os.listdir(src)
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../build/iPhoneOS-arm64/install/include/opencv2'
```

Can someone tell me how I can fix that or what the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sh: cmake: command not found
```

This project uses `cmake` to build, it's a command line utility.  cmake is not included on Mac OS X as a part of the Xcode 5 tools - you need to install it yourself.  http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html

Comment: so I can build it now with cmake, but to complete build fails anyway and no framework was built. there are some files missing. maybe you are familiar with the opencv framework. where I can get it or how to solve the problem? /Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/julesair/Open_CV/ios/build/iPhoneOS-arm64/3rdparty/libjpeg/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/libjpeg.build/Objects-normal/arm64/jmemansi.o (No such file or directory)
Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit  code 1

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about the OpenCV project.