# How to build zlib for arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, zlib, ogre, arm64

I use an open-source rendering library (Ogre3D) which has a dependency on zlib.

In XCode5, I noticed that when building for iOS, zlib will not build if 64-bit (arm64) architecture is indicated by ARCHS setting.

I get errors about "implicit function declaration" relating to `LSEEK` macro, `read` and `write` functions. I looked up `LSEEK` in gzlib.c:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(__BORLANDC__)
#  define LSEEK _lseeki64
#else
#if defined(_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE) && _LFS64_LARGEFILE-0
#  define LSEEK lseek64
#else
#  define LSEEK lseek
#endif
#endif
```

My guess is something here is wrong, but I don't know what. And as for `read()` and `write()` I have no clue.

Comment: We are using the official *zlib* library (version 1.2.8 as of yesterday), but we have a modified `CMakeList.txt` file, with many things stripped out. Perhaps compare ours to the one from the official *zlib* library to check if there are some mandatory things in order for it to compile on arm64 that we need to add.

Comment: BY 'we' you mean Ogre3D, right? I didn't realise customized versions were used.

Comment: Yes, by '*we*' I mean Ogre3D (or more specifically the Ogre3D dev team I am part of). Should have made that clearer,sorry. Again: The source code is the official version, just the CMakeList.txt is different.

Comment: Also: Did you try to manually define `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` and set `_LFS64_LARGEFILE-0` to check whether used `lseek64` would solve the issue?

Answer (score 12):

Try adding an `#include <unistd.h>` in gzguts.h.

Comment: Also works if you're having problems compiling zlib for OpenCV3.1.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution in that scenario is not to build *zlib* yourself at all, since it already comes pre-compiled with the iOS SDK (also for arm64).

This [latest commit](https://bitbucket.org/cabalistic/ogredeps/commits/630ebe7bdf480490c451b0535f3122ce56df3257) fixes it also in the official Ogre dependencies repository.

Apart from that, there is this other option from [this Ogre3D thread](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=80324#p503927):

> With **ARCHS = ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT**, projects like zlip were failing. When I changed this to **ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT**, they built OK. I've discovered the former evaluates to "armv7 armv7s arm64" while the latter currently evaluates to "armv7 armv7s". So I think zlip won't build for arm64.

That would mean that Ogre3D parts are compiled for 64-bit, where as some dependencies such as *zlib* stay 32-bit.

Comment: I think that's just describing the same problem... it doesn't build for arm64. While _not_ building for arm64 is an option, 32 bit apps introduce extra overhead on 64-bit iOS and it doesn't seem a long-term fix!

Comment: I see and concur. Have a look at this answer then. Maybe adding that `#include <unistd.h>` solves the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20143790/1947205