# Compiling OpenCV for iOS fails - Cmake fails

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv, cmake

I try to compile OpenCV for ios. I get these errors all the time. I tried it with different versions of opencv, but the result is the same.

I run this:
python platforms/ios/build_framework.py ios_opencv_build

I have python, cmake and g++ compilers installed. 
Does anyone have an idea what these errors mean and what I should do to compile successfully?

```
  -- Setting up iPhoneOS toolchain
    -- iPhoneOS toolchain loaded
    -- Setting up iPhoneOS toolchain
    -- iPhoneOS toolchain loaded
    -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 5.1.0
    -- The C compiler identification is Clang 5.1.0
    -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
    CMake Error at /opt/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
      get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


    CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
    -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Failed
    -- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
    CMake Error at /opt/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
      get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


    CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
    -- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Failed
    -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W
    CMake Error at /opt/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
      get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like problem with old version of CMake. Try updating to newest CMake available from their website (which OS version and CMake version do you use?)

See also: http://answers.opencv.org/question/6789/problem-with-installation-opencv/
and this (I think this problem was similar): https://github.com/urho3d/Urho3D/issues/308

Comment: cmake version 2.8.12 & Mac OSX 10.9.2 I checked that link and downloaded even v 2.4.3.1 and compiled. Its the same result.

Comment: Its working. Incredible. It was really because of an old version of CMake. I had 2.8.12.1 which shows only 2.8.12 on command line when you ask and I was thinking I had the newest version 2.8.12.2. I installed it using port again, and ran the python script, and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I encountered another error, could you please take a look if you have time?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156007/compile-opencv-for-ios-fails