# Compile OpenCV for iOS fails

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, build, cmake

Does anyone have idea why this error occurs?

I run `$ python platforms/ios/build_framework.py ios` to create the `framework` of OpenCV for iOS. But the install failed.

*Platform information:* OpenCV latest commit from today, CMake 2.8.12.2, XCode 5.1.1, Mac OSX 10.9.2

I followed this tutorial: [Installing Opencv For iOS](http://7ip5.blogspot.de/2013/07/installing-opencv-for-ios.html)

```
** INSTALL FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Libtool ios/build/iPhoneSimulator-x86_64/modules/world/UninstalledProducts/libopencv_world.a normal x86_64
(1 failure)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 112, in <module>
    build_framework(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), "../..")), os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1]))
  File "platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 104, in build_framework
    put_framework_together(srcroot, dstroot)
  File "platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 80, in put_framework_together
    shutil.copytree(tdir0 + "/install/include/opencv2", dstdir + "/Headers")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 171, in copytree
    names = os.listdir(src)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../build/iPhoneOS-arm64/install/include/opencv2'
```

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be surprised if the latest commit has some problems. Try a release version first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

molbdnilo is right:) Building the latest release is always better idea than building the latest commit. Thanks.
I have downloaded the latest release of OpenCV which is 2.4.8 right now and built it again. Everything worked fine.

Comment: This is true and a good workaround to the problem in your question, but it is not an answer to the question regarding why the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Just today I've faced the same problem and solved it with a simple command:

```
brew install cmake
```

This solution was described [here](http://appcofe.blogspot.com.es/2016/11/fix-build-error-of-opencv-ios-oserror.html).

Answer (score 0):

As @enreas mentioned in his answer, the problem is that you don't have `cmake` installed. That would solve the problem.

There are many ways to do this, the easiers are via either homebrew or MacPorts:

homebrew version:

```
brew install cmake
```

MacPorts:

```
port install cmake
```